# Back button Flutter on a return Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter, so I apologize if the question is very basic.

My problem is with the back button... when I press it it sends me to a black page, but when I press the android back button it works fine. Is there a way to make that button the same as the one on the device?

In Android that button is not necessary, but in iOS it is.

My code is:

```
class FindDevicesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool scanResult = false;
    bool connectedResult = false;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),
        title: Text('Find Devices'),
        actions: <Widget>[],
      ),
```

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/example
(The example code doesn't have that function)

I tried with:

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),

onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); },
```

But it does not work. It doesn't go back to the previous page, but to a black page with nothing.

Comment: Have you embedded your flutter app into an existing iOS/Android app ?

Comment: Yes. When I write: **onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RegisterScreen.routeName),** (I see that in the app it is what we use to navigate) I get an error: **Bad state: Stream has already listened to.**

Comment: you don't need to manually set the action for the app bar back button, it will be automatically shown to the user and will be handled. You can remove the part ``leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
        ),``

Comment: I already did that, but the black page is still coming up blank. I see in another section of the app code that it has a similar button and it does work. Why with this new screen (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/example) did not work?

Comment: Is there an alternative? Mimic the device's "Back" button.

Comment: So when you press back are you expecting to navigate out of Flutter Controller/View to the native app ? If so I think that should be handled via a message handler so that native will dismiss flutter controller

Comment: I just want to do the same thing that Android's back button does. Only that. Is there a way to mimic the function of that button? To do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using:

```
class FindDevicesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool scanResult = false;
    bool connectedResult = false;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
        ),
        title: Text('Find Devices'),
        actions: <Widget>[],
      ),
```

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm new to flutter too but I had a similar problem and I solved it by using `pushReplacement`

```
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(route)
```

I don't know if this is correct or not but this was my workaround.

Comment: Bad state: Stream has already listened to.